# Attaching Jenkins node in Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to attach a build to a node in Jenkins Pipeline which will be created and attached in one of Jenkins build.

Eg:

```
node('tester1') {
    build 'test_job1'
}
node('tester2') {
    build 'test_job1'
}
```

Only problem is that the node 'tester2' will be created and attached in the build 'test_job1'

So when I try to run this pipeline, it always fails because tester2 node is not present at the start of execution of pipeline.

Has anyone implement something similar before?
Thanks.

Comment: I assume the `2` on line 4 is a typo (should be `{`), and not not in your code, because it works when i do it

Comment: Hey @Rik 
Yes its a typo I have edited it now

Comment: When does it fail? As soon as it should start running on the second node? You can use node labels instead of names as well. Even combine with `&&` and `||`. Are you sure the node is fully online when the script gets ther?